# Instance method Exception : Event is not defined

Tags: jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

New to Jest, trying to write a basic test case to check the Dropdown feature in Jest.

I have tried the below code:

```
test( "update state with dropdown", async () => {

    let wrapper = mount( <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ “/workflow/new" ]}><Workflow/></MemoryRouter> );

    expect.assertions( 7 );

    // Mock validation API calls
    let apiWorkflowPromise = Promise.resolve( apiWorkflowResult );
    get.mockImplementation( () => apiWorkflowPromise );

    // ACT
    let instance = wrapper.find( “Workflow” ).instance();
    instance.handleWorkflowDropDownChange( { target: { value: “NewZealand” } } );
    await expect( apiWorkflowPromise ).resolves.toBeDefined();

    // ASSERT
    let selectedDiagnosticWorkflow = instance.state.selectedWorkflow;
    let supportedParameters = instance.state.workflow.supportedParameters;
    expect( selectedWorkflow ).toEqual( “NewZealand” );

 } );
```

Getting the below error:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined
>   at Workflow.handleWorkflowDropDownChange

Comment: can you share the code for `handleWorkflowDropDownChange`?

Comment: thanks @brian-lives-outdoors . Issue was in the function itself.